# What is a fast, pythonic way to sum items in a list at specified indices?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have to sum up a subset of items in a list. The numbers I use to calculate the indices are given in another list. The indices may change, but the list I'm summing from does not. Both lists are of known size. This bit of code is in a nested loop in my program, and it's by far the slowest part.

I need a fast and clean way to do this in Python 3.

An obvious solution I have tried is just hardcoding the sum of all the different items. I've also tried a much cleaner solution using `enumerate` and summing a comprehension. The problem is that the latter is much slower than the former.

The exact index to use is `2 * i + x` where `i` is the index in `indices` and `x` is the number in `indices`. (The indices list represents a set of choices between values concatenated into the lookup table.)

```py
# sample code - the real lists are much larger

lookup = [7, 10, 1, 4, 1, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6]
indices = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

# hardcoded solution
s = lookup[2 * 0 + indices[0]] + lookup[2 * 1 + indices[1]] + lookup[2 * 2 + indices[2]] + lookup[2 * 3 + indices[3]] + lookup[2 * 4 + indices[4]]

# Pythonic solution with enumerate
s = sum(lookup[2 * i + x] for i, x in enumerate(indices))
```

I have tested both of these options using [perf](https://perf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The clean solution with `enumerate` is just over 3 times slower than the hardcoded version. The rest of the code is fairly optimized, so my whole program is almost 3 times slower if I go with the clean version.

Is there something faster I could do? Answers that require preprocessing the `lookup` list in some way are okay: that list is only built once but used many times.

Edit: here is a complete example of a case where hardcoding lookups to a list seems to be much faster than any alternative. The following code runs in Pypy3 in 0.27s, and the commented out slow version runs in 2.8s. (Obviously there are faster ways to do this particular task.)

```
from itertools import product

lookup = [1, 7, 7, 1, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 8, 8, 9, 6, 5, 10, 3, 4, 7, 10, 1, 3, 0, 1, 7, 1, 3, 4, 2, 9]
largest_sum = 0
largest_sum_indices = []

for indices in product(list(range(0,2)), repeat=15):
    # simulate checking many different lookup lists
    for _ in range(200):
        s = lookup[2 * 0 + indices[0]] + lookup[2 * 1 + indices[1]] + lookup[2 * 2 + indices[2]] + lookup[2 * 3 + indices[3]] + lookup[2 * 4 + indices[4]] + lookup[2 * 5 + indices[5]] + lookup[2 * 6 + indices[6]] + lookup[2 * 7 + indices[7]] + lookup[2 * 8 + indices[8]] + lookup[2 * 9 + indices[9]] + lookup[2 * 10 + indices[10]] + lookup[2 * 11 + indices[11]] + lookup[2 * 12 + indices[12]] + lookup[2 * 13 + indices[13]] + lookup[2 * 14 + indices[14]]
        # clean method is too slow
        #s = sum(lookup[i * 2 + x] for i,x in enumerate(indices))
        if s > largest_sum:
            largest_sum = s
            largest_sum_indices = indices

print(largest_sum)
print(largest_sum_indices)
```

Comment: Have you considered using C? Or set least numpy?

Comment: How much faster are we taking about here, in absolute terms? How many elements are in the real `indices`?

Comment: "The rest of the code is fairly optimized, so my whole program is almost 3 times slower if I go with the clean version." I don't believe this, unless your program is 4 lines long.

Comment: You can believe it or not, but it's true. The whole program is just looping over a bunch of different `indices`, performing some very minimal calculations, and storing the result. I checked it just now - with pypy3 and some test input, the "slow" version takes ~2.07 seconds. The hardcoded version takes 0.7 seconds. The only difference between the programs is the one line in my sample code.

Comment: Wow. That's a) an actual difference, and b) pretty amazing. Could you post the entire program, out at least a sample that I can test the disparity with? I'm really interested now. Perhaps you can leverage the uniformity of the lookup, or change the way you drove the indices to just be raw indices? I'd love to take a closer look either way.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've added a larger example that mostly illustrates what I'm trying to do. The real thing has more than two binary options and involves comparing results from multiple lookup lists, and is still much larger. The data gets loaded from a CSV.

Comment: Wait, you're trying to find the largest sum possible by talking one number from each successive pair? Why not just find the index of the maximum element in each pair?

Comment: I've added an answer that should take a fraction of a second for a million elements.

Comment: I didn't bother removing the original answer because I think it has merit in the context of the original question.

Comment: That was only an example of what I was trying to do in order to illustrate the slowness of using `enumerate`. What I actually need to do is build a histogram of the results showing which `lookup` has the maximum sum for every input. I don't think that can be solved your way. For the problem I'm really trying to solve, I believe the way I'm doing it is fastest.

Comment: I just made a slight modification to simulate checking many different lookup lists. (Still not doing the histogram thing.) Hardcoded version takes 0.28s on Pypy3, version with `enumerate` takes 2.68s.

Comment: I suggest you accept an answer for the current question and ask another. Constantly shifting the requirements makes any answers already posted useless for future readers. If you feel that my understanding of your problem is incomplete, an explanation is one thing, but changing the meaning of the question is not recommended.

Comment: Ping me when you post another question, so I know where to look.

Comment: I haven't changed the meaning of the question, you just misunderstood the purpose of my example. My question is still about the fastest way to get the sum of specific items in an list, which I believe I have to do for my code to work.

Comment: yes, my answer only addresses the actual code you show. I'm suggesting that instead of asking me to accept your explanation of what it represents, you show me. Partly because I'm not sure I grasp the meaning of it. This looks like a project that you've put some significant effort into, and it doesn't come as easily to me as it does to you, although I'm sure it's simple for you. At the same time, I'm suggesting you post another question, since a full explanation with a more complete example would change the meaning of this one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my solution works in the updated case too, but since you don't use `_` anywhere, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `itemgetter()` for fast lookup:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import count

lookup = [7, 10, 1, 4, 1, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6]
indices = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

sum(itemgetter(*[i + j for i, j in zip(count(step=2), indices)])(lookup))
# 27
```

Comment: Unfortunately, testing with `perf` says that this is even slower than the enumerate version. The enumerate version takes 1.38 us to run, your final line takes 1.84 us. Both are much worse than the hardcoded version which takes only 0.41 us.

Comment: @adamf  Try `lambda x, y: x + y` instead of `add`.

Comment: That's even worse. 2.31 us.

Comment: Try `[i+j for i,j in zip(count(step=2), indices)]` instead of `map()`.

Comment: Yup, any time you use map is generally going to be slower than the equivalent comprehension.

Comment: This new version took 2.1 us. Faster than the previous version, but still far behind even my enumerate code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good task for numpy. It allows you to vectorize many of the operations you are doing, running C implementations under the hood.

```
import numpy as np

lookup = np.array([7, 10, 1, 4, 1, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6], dtype=np.int)
indices = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1], dtype=np.int)

real_indices = np.arange(0, 2 * indices.size, 2) + indices
s = lookup[real_indices].sum()
```

Comment: Unfortunately doing it this way is even slower than enumerate. According to `perf` the last three lines take an average of 10.4 us to run, much worse than the enumerate code which takes only 1.38 us. And that's still worse than the hardcoded version which runs in only 0.41 us.

Comment: Those results may be misleading, especially if they include the import :) The idea is to pre-wrap the lookup just once, then derive the indices so they are a numpy array to begin with, not a list that you need to wrap. You can probably squeeze some gains by avoiding the dtype computation, so I've edited that in.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you really need to re-evaluate your algorithm instead of attempting to squeeze out cycles from innocent code if the edit is indicative of what you are really trying to do.

Let's start by describing in words what your code does. You have a lookup array of size 2N. You are assigning a bit (0 or 1) to indicate which element you will select from each successive pair, and add up the N selected elements. By going through every bit combination from 0 to 2**N-1, you hope to find the maximum sum of N elements.

I would posit that simply inspecting the N pairs of elements in a single pass will give you the correct sum and indices, if you still want those. You can do this in N steps, not N * 2**N.

Here is a really basic, totally unoptimized, solution that I bet will scale better than the one in the question:

```
lookup = ...
N = len(lookup) // 2
largest_sum = 0
largest_sum_indices = [0] * N
for i in range(N):
    if lookup[2 * i + 1] > lookup[2 * i]:
        largest_sum_indices[i] = 1
        largest_sum += lookup[2 * i + 1]
    else:
        largest_sum += lookup[2 * i]
```

Notice that I don't call any functions besides `len` and just use a basic `for` loop.

Here is an optimized numpy version:

```
import numpy as np

lookup = np.array(...)
largest_sum_indices = np.argmax(lookup.reshape(lookup.size // 2, 2), axis=1)
largest_sum = lookup[2 * np.arange(largest_sum_indices.size) + largest_sum_indices]
```

While your own tests will show you which algorithm works best for you, keep in mind that either of the options here could handily process a few million elements without making the user too antsy, while somerhing that scales as O(N * 2**N) would take longer than the heat death of many universes. Any time you use `product`, there is a good chance of a better solution being available.